# Convert string to sobject type in salesforce

Tags: string, list, object

I have Object name in string I want to featch the list of records of that object.
How to fetch the list from string .
My cod eis like this:

```
String objectName = 'Account';
List<ObjectName> lstObject = new  List<ObjectName>([select id from ObjectName limit 10]);
```

But I am getting error like

> Invalid type: objectName

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in List give a generic type object... Like string, integer, etc.... Don't pass a straight object.

Comment: yes but I want the type from string .So How i convert the string into sobject  type?

Comment: do this... List<String> lstObject = new  List<String>([select id from ObjectName limit 10]);... by the way i don't think your sql query will work here...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have got any feedback for this question, I have seen this now by chance.

You can try something like this:

```
String objName = 'Account';
String query = 'Select Id From '+objName+ ' Limit 10';
List<SObject> objL = Database.query(query);
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.